# Firebase Multiple Accounts are signed at the same time

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want my users to sign in with multiple accounts (Not linking multiple providers)

like gmail, it allows you to use multiple signed in accounts at the same time
you can check all inboxes for all accounts at the same time

e.g. I am a User and I want to use two accounts
john@example.com & john21@example.com

I want both emails signed in (there are two auth tokens in this case)

I have searched about it in Firebase docs, I couldn't find anything

Is this possible in Firebase Auth?

Comment: use custom claims and provide the uids you want allow access to this way you can login the user for as many accounts you want. the only limit is 1000 chars limit on custom tokens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From one project, no i don't think you can have two users signed in.

You can create another Firebase project and add your app there (you'll be able to add your sha-1 on either one). You can then look up their approach to using two Firebase projects in one app.

You'll be able to sign in with two users in this way if there are two projects to sign in with. You'll have to manage your users across both the databases on your own i.e same user will have to have an account with same credentials made in both the projects.

It's complicated but it can be done. I use anonymous sign in from two separate projects simultaneously in my app, both users are the same... Just their projects are different.

Answer (score 4):

I was thinking about this issue, reading through the documentation and found that you can re-authenticate a user by credential. So maybe you can do it this way:

when a new user wants to sign in you take his info as `AuthCredential` object like this:

```
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential("user@example.com", "password1234");
//there is also GoogleAuthProvider, FacebookAuthProvider...
```

then to actually signing him in you use `signInWithCredential(AuthCredential)` :

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential);
```

Now you need to save the `credential` object and the `user` object somewhere safe.
If you want to add new user you do the same and save the new objects.
After that whenever in your app you want to switch between the users you get that user's object and call `reauthenticate(AuthCredential)` method:

```
myFirstUserObject.reauthenticate(myFirstUserCredential);
```

I didn't really test this, you think it could work? I don't know exactly how to save the objects and if there is a safe way to implement it without exposing each user's credential?

Comment: This definitely works. It's basically the same approach as saving the email and password (if that's the logging in method). But the question is: Is there a safe way to save these data? A way that keeps the user data privacy?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple simultaneous logins in the same project is not supported with Firebase Auth.

You could possibly have multiple logins between multiple projects if you manually initialize the Firebase SDK with the settings for the other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have pointed out, one Firebase app can have one authenticated user. But one web app can have multiple Firebase apps.

This means you can create an app and put a user there. Then you can reuse that user in the main application using `auth.updateCurrentUser`.

```js
export class AuthApp {
  private app = initializeApp(ENVIRONMENT, 'authApp');
  private auth = getAuth(app);

  getUser(): User | null {
    return this.auth.currentUser;
  }

  setUser(user: User | null) {
    this.auth.updateCurrentUser(user);
  }
}
```

```js
class MainApp {
  private app = initializeApp(ENVIRONMENT);
  private auth = getAuth(app);

  forExample() {
    const authApp = new AuthApp();
    authApp.setUser(this.auth.currentUser);

    // sign in a new user
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.auth, 'new.user@gmail.com', '123');

    // restore the old user
    this.auth.updateCurrentUser(authApp.getUser());
  }
}
```